# What is the impact of a lower TG for an RF Board?

Tags: rf, temperature, pcb-fabrication

I have a board that contains a WiFi module (2.4GHz). Does Tg have an effect on RF performance in any way ?

If the material can satisfy the other constraints, such as Dk, Df etc.. would the Tg be a factor in material selection for RF ?

I should note that this is a relatively high volume unit so it's extremely cost-sensitive.

Comment: is your application one in which the glass transition temperature seems relevant?

Comment: It def isn't but don't know if there are other parameters that would be associated with a higher Tg. My Asian cm says go with 130degc but North American shop uses isola 377hr which has a tg of 170 degC.

Comment: well, that's not how specs work, luckily: You know which properties matter, and then you check the datasheet of the board substrate whether they are given for your operational range. All other parameters do not matter – whether they are Tg, or density, or color, or taste, or usability as cutting board for carrots ... ;)

Comment: Woohoo for clear and non dependent specs! Lol :p

Comment: I'd ask your Asian manufacturer to supply you with the datasheet of the substrate that they will guarantee to use. For RF stuff, you don't want them to switch to something with slightly differently epsilon (even just slightly different isotropicity in epsilon) between production runs.

Comment: If the dk did change, would that be enough to have to recertify with fcc / CE / other?

Comment: what's dk? I don't think it's as much a certification problem as a technical one. (certification usually is "if the device doesn't change from what was certified", and if a material change has no functional consequences, that would usually be no problem)

Comment: Dk is the epsilon (dielectric constant)

Comment: well, you change the epsilon and suddenly your transmission lines have a different impedance. That changes what your board *does*.